# Is there a way to create a cubic interpolation function for scattered data in 3D (x, y, z) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, cubic-spline

I am looking for a function in Matlab that constructs a cubic interpolation function, `Z = f(X, Y)`, for irregularly spaced data. Basically, [Matlab's `griddedInterpolant`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html) function is what I'm looking for in terms of interpolation `Method`, whereas I'm looking for [Matlab's `scatteredInterpolant`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html) in terms of the regularity requirements of the input data. Namely, `scatteredInterpolant` only offers `nearest`, `linear`, and `natural` interpolation `Methods`.

I require cubic interpolation, because I use this function in a program that requires twice continuously differentiable functions. So, `makima` or `pchip` as interpolation methods would suffice, too, though I prefer `cubic`.

I *did* find [this function on Matlab FEX](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10056-scattered-data-interpolation-and-approximation-using-radial-base-functions), but with its poor documentation I'm not exactly sure if this is what I'm looking for. Moreover, it says it's more computationally expensive than `griddedInterpolant` and `scatteredInterpolant`, which doesn't really fit my needs.

Moreover, cubic interpolation to map the data onto a regularly spaced 3D grid and subsequently calling `griddedInterpolant` isn't a possibility for me.

Comment: `scatteredInterpolant` does not do cubic, because its very expensive computationally. If that does not fit your needs you find yourself on a bad spot, as it is not possible to do something more complex and for it to be faster. Any implementation would take long.

Comment: I can’t even imagine what cubic interpolation would look like on irregularly sampled data. But you can look into methods such as [thin plate splines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline), which lead to a smooth function. [Shepard’s method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) might also be applicable.